# Ways to call a native iPhone application from another native iPhone application

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios

What are the various ways to call a native iPhone application from another native iPhone application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the url scheme built into iOS. For example, you could call Safari with a url because it is registered as the application which handles the `http` URL scheme

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]]
```

The `openURL:` method is an instance method of the singleton UIApplication instance, on which you can call any application installed which registers in its plist an ability to handle some sort of input data.

[Here's a list of common url schemes in iOS.](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)

A little known way to detect the existence of another application on a device is to use `canOpenURL:` on the same singleton instance:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"cydia://"]])
{
    NSLog(@"cydia installed");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"cydia not installed");
}
```