# Help me to run a iPhone application

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am going to develop a iPhone application.

In that i need to run another iPhone app when the user clicks on the button.

Is it possible to run a iPhone app from another iPhone app?

If possible, Please let me know your inputs on this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[copy and paste of a previous answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504922/ways-to-call-a-native-iphone-application-from-another-native-iphone-application/4504939#4504939) for the click-averse]

You can use the url scheme built into iOS. For example, you could call Safari with a url because it is registered as the application which handles the `http` URL scheme

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]]
```

The `openURL:` method is an instance method of the singleton UIApplication instance, on which you can call any application installed which registers in its plist an ability to handle some sort of input data.

[Here's a list of common url schemes in iOS.](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes)

A little known way to detect the existence of another application on a device is to use `canOpenURL:` on the same singleton instance:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"cydia://"]])
{
    NSLog(@"cydia installed");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"cydia not installed");
}
```

Comment: i have my sampleApp in my simulator but when i run your above code it always returning not installed.why this happening?

Comment: You need to change 'cydia://' in the above code to the app you want to test. If you want to see if Safari is installed (ie, it is), change it to 'http://'.

Comment: if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myapp://sampleApp"]])
   {
    NSLog(@"cydia installed"); 
    NSString *stringURL = @"myapp://sampleApp";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
   }
   else
   {
    NSLog(@"cydia not installed");
   }Now it shows that it is installed.but not opening that application. pls help me up.

Comment: "This method guarantees that that if openURL: is called, another application will be launched to handle it. It does not guarantee that the full URL is valid." Change the formatting of the url, it should work thereafter.

Answer (score 1):

Only if that other app is already installed and run and has been designed to register a custom URL handler to itself with the OS.

The your app can run it by using that custom URL scheme.

Comment: thanks for the reply...yes the other app is installed already.can you show me an example code how it can be.

Comment: Do you know that app's registered custom URL scheme?

Answer (score 1):

If the app has a custom URL Schema and you know what it is, then it is possible to launch another app form yours.

Answer (score 1):

When user pressed the button, your current app will close and run the new app..

Yea.. Its possible.. BUT you must know the "short link" of the other app.. I tried it before and even successfully transferred data from the lite version to the full version..

Its called url scheme..

Here's a link:
http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

Hope it can achieve what you want..